# How to remove pending notification request when using uuidString as identifier swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilocalnotification, identifier

I am using local notifications and storing the data in core data. I am using the editingStyle .delete to delete the reminder with a swipe to the left action. Figured out how to delete the data with context.delete but the reminder still displays since I have not removed the pending notification when swipe delete. I have used             UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
and as figured after just deleting just one reminder all the others even though not deleted from tableView or core data the notification doesn't show as expected.

When creating my notification I am using "UUID().uuidString" as my identifier for my UNNotificationRequest to create a unique identifier every time the user created a new reminder. My question is how do I remove a pending notification when using unique identifier with  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: )

Here is my code when creating the notification and when deleting it:

```
@IBAction func dateReminder(){
    
    guard let dateVc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dateVc") as? DateViewController else {
        return
    }
    dateVc.completion = {title,body,date in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
            let new = Reminder(context: self.context)
            new.title = title
            new.body = body
            new.detailsDate = date
            new.detailsBool = false
            
            self.reminder.append(new)
            self.saveData()
            
            
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = title
            content.body = body
            content.sound = .default
            
            let dateSelected = date
            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour , .minute , .second], from: dateSelected), repeats: false)
            let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
                if let e = error{
                    print("An error occurred. \(e)")
                }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    navigationController?.pushViewController(dateVc, animated: true)
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete{
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        
        context.delete(reminder[indexPath.row])
        reminder.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: )
        tableView.endUpdates()
        self.saveData()
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You must of course keep a reference to the identifier, perhaps in a dictionary where the key is a unique property from Reminder and the value is the identifier.

Comment: I hope I understood correctly. When using a dictionary to store the identifier I have problems using that reference in my notificationRequest since it asks me for String not a Dictionary. Also i noticed when trying to remove notification with identifier it asks for an array of strings and I am just trying to delete one. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: I thought you understood how to use a dictionary in this situation but maybe not. My point was that you store some reference to the Reminder object together with the notification uuid for that object so that later when the object is deleted you can lookup the uuid in the dictionary by using the reference property from the object and then use that uuid to remove the notification

Answer (score 3):

If you want to delete all pending notifications requests, call this function

```
@objc func cancelNotifications() -> Void {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
}
```

Comment: If you read the question carefully you see that OP has already tried this but want to delete individual notifications.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I left it on purpose, as it might be useful to someone else  ... Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

To Delete Reminders Using Identifiers I Use Following Code...

```
func cancelReminderWithIdentifier(identifier : String) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests { (notificationRequests) in
       var identifiers: [String] = []
       for notification:UNNotificationRequest in notificationRequests {
           if notification.identifier == identifier {
              identifiers.append(notification.identifier)
           }
       }
        self.UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: identifiers)
    }
}
```

Pass identifier in function and You will have your Notification Delete.

For Saving Your UUID,

```
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
            if let e = error{
                print("An error occurred. \(e)")
            } else {
                //You Can Save Your UUID and Other Data Here
                //Just Example
                CoreDataOperation.addNewModel(UUIDString : uuidString, title : title)
            }
        }
```

Note : - You can find Other Threads useful for Using Core Data.

Comment: This helps when I am using a hardcoded identifier but I am using a unique identifier that changes every time the user creates a new reminder. I can't figure out how to save the unique identifier and then remove the notification of that unique identifier, not remove all or remove all the notifications under one single hardcoded identifier. I hope I explain my self correctly. @Namra Parmar

Comment: When you Set reminder Using your code, after setting notification add your unique idetifier to core data(Or Notification data As You want).  After that get data from core data and get individual idetifier and then you can use above function.@Chamoy